# groupby with diff function

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, mean

I have a groupby with a diff function, however I want to add an extra mean column for heart rate, how can I do this the best way?

this is the code

```
data= pd.DataFrame(
    [[Timestamp('2022-08-05 10:11:04'), 140, 120],
    [Timestamp('2022-08-05 10:11:05'), 160, 155],
    [Timestamp('2022-08-05 10:11:06'), 230, 156],
    [Timestamp('2022-08-05 10:11:07'), 230, 155],
    [Timestamp('2022-08-05 10:11:08'), 230, 160],
    [Timestamp('2022-08-05 10:11:09'), 140, 130],
    [Timestamp('2022-08-05 10:11:10'), 140, 131],
    [Timestamp('2022-08-05 10:11:11'), 230, 170]],
    columns=['timestamp', 'power', 'heart rate'])

m = data['power'].gt(200) #fill in power value
gb = (-data['timestamp'].diff(-1))[m].groupby([(~m).cumsum()).sum()
gb= gb.groupby((~m).cumsum()).sum()
gb
```

where should I add in the piece of code to calculate the average heart rate?

output will be the amount of seconds in high power zone and then i would like to add the average heart rate during this period. like this

```
gb = pd.DataFrame(
    [[Timestamp('00:00:04'), 210, 145],
    [Timestamp('00:00:15'), 250, 155],
    [Timestamp('00:01:00'), 230, 180],
   
    columns=['time at high intensity', ' avg power', ' avg heart rate'])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create helper column from by difference and then aggregate by it and another column in named aggregation in [`GroupBy.agg`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.agg.html):

```
m = data['power'].gt(200) #fill in power value
gb = (data.assign(new=-data['timestamp'].diff(-1))[m]
          .groupby((~m).cumsum())
          .agg(time_at_high_intensity=('new','sum'),
               avg_power=('power','mean'), 
               avg_heart_rate=('heart rate','mean')))
                                               
print (gb)
      time_at_high_intensity  avg_power  avg_heart_rate
power                                                  
2            0 days 00:00:03        230             157
4            0 days 00:00:00        230             170
```

Comment: one last question, now i have what i want, for all different intervals, how can i add a counter by date. So count interval 1 of the day then 2 etc. For each day the counter should start from 1 again, what will be the easiest?

Comment: @pepijn - Do you think new column in input dataframe? Then use `data['counter']= data.groupby(data['timestamp'].dt.date).cumcount()`

Comment: this won't work i think as i want to count from the gb dataframe, as this has multiple rows for same date, and i want to make a counter for the number of rows per date

Comment: @pepijn - in gb is not datetimes, onkly intervals (timedeltas). So not sure if understand what is logic. there is no information about datetimes.

Comment: yes i understand that, but i am hoping there is an easy way to implement this in some way

Comment: i've added in the unique dates as a string, so could a condition work

Comment: @pepijn - Hmm, is possible add expected ouput from sample data? I think what should be in counter column, I try underrstand logic from it. Only done need any numbers, I need numbers count from sample data posted in question

Comment: ````
gb = pd.DataFrame(
    [[Timestamp('00:00:04'), 210, 145],
    [Timestamp('00:00:15'), 250, 155],
    [Timestamp('00:01:00'), 230, 180],
   
    columns=['time at high intensity', ' avg power', ' avg heart rate'])
````

so these can include multiples dates, so i want a counter to count the number of rows  for each date

Comment: @pepijn - I think counter column

Comment: yes some sort of counter column, based on a date column that is in object form (not visible in the data i posted here)